# Getting Outputs from aws cloudformation describe-stacks

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am using the below to get the [stack information](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html) I want via AWS Cli:

```
aws cloudformation --region ap-southeast-2 describe-stacks --stack-name mystack
```

It's returning result OK:

```
{
    "Stacks": [
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:mystackid", 
            "LastUpdatedTime": "2017-01-13T04:59:17.472Z", 
            "Tags": [], 
            "Outputs": [
                {
                    "OutputKey": "Ec2Sg", 
                    "OutputValue": "sg-97e13dff"
                }, 
                {
                    "OutputKey": "DbUrl", 
                    "OutputValue": "myUrl"
                }
            ], 
            "CreationTime": "2017-01-13T03:27:18.893Z", 
            "StackName": "mystack", 
            "NotificationARNs": [], 
            "StackStatus": "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE", 
            "DisableRollback": false
        }
    ]
}
```

But I do not know how to return only the value of OutputValue which is myUrl

As I do not need the rest, just myUrl.

Is that possible via aws cloudformation describe-stacks?

**Edit**

I just realize I can use --[query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html):

```
--query "Stacks[0].Outputs[1].OutputValue"
```

will get exactly what I want but I would like to use DbUrl else if the number of Outputs changes, my result will be unexpected.

Answer (score 153):

I got the answer, use the below:

```
--query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==`DbUrl`].OutputValue' --output text
```

Or

```
--query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==`DbUrl`].OutputValue' --output text
```

Or

```
--query 'Stacks[?StackName==`mystack`][].Outputs[?OutputKey==`DbUrl`].OutputValue' --output text
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for today.

Comment: Just for anyone else, I had to use `"` rather than `'`

Comment: If you want to fetch multiple outputs (tab separated in one line) you can use

    `--query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==\`ParamOne\` || OutputKey==\`ParamTwo\` || OutputKey==\`ParamThree\`].OutputValue' --output text`

Comment: However, the order in which parameters are returned is random and you can't rely on their index to extract them. For multiple parameters to be retrieved reliably return them as json and use jq to extract them, ie. 
`--query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==\`ParamOne\` || OutputKey==\`ParamTwo\` || OutputKey==\`ParamThree\`]' >> params.txt; one=$(cat params.txt | jq -r '.[] | select(.OutputKey=="ParamOne") | .OutputValue'); two=$(cat params.txt | jq -r '.[] | select(.OutputKey=="ParamTwo") | .OutputValue'); three=$(cat params.txt | jq -r '.[] | select(.OutputKey=="ParamThree") | .OutputValue')`

Comment: @Koka I'm gonna shamelessly promote my own alternative to `jq` here: https://github.com/jedwards1211/lambduh

Comment: `--query 'Stacks[0].Outputs' | duh 'json => require("lodash").fromPairs(json.map(({OutputKey, OutputValue}) => [OutputKey, OutputValue]))'`

Comment: For OP's example it would output `{"Ec2Sg": "sg-97e13dff", "DbUrl": "myUrl"}`.  Much better to get the values by name than by index.

Comment: more useful examples in the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter

Comment: واي واي واي .. terraform output <name> . imagine

Comment: I had to use ``

Answer (score 27):

While querying works, it may prove problematic if you have multiple stacks.  Realistically, you should *probably* be leveraging exports for things that are distinct and authoritative.

By way of example - if you modified your CloudFormation snippet to look like this:

```
"Outputs" : {
  "DbUrl" : {
    "Description" : "My Database Url",
    "Value" : "myUrl",
    "Export" : {
      "Name" : "DbUrl"
    }
  }
}
```

Then you could use:

```
aws cloudformation list-exports --query "Exports[?Name==\`DbUrl\`].Value" --no-paginate --output text
```

to retrieve it.  Exports are required to be unique - only one stack can export any given name.  This way, you're assured that you get the right value, every time.  If you attempt to create a new stack that exports a name that already exists elsewhere, that stack creation will fail.

Comment: Is it true that the stack creation will fail? I find the output to be duplicated

Comment: Check the notes on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html. Specifically: "For each AWS account, Export names must be unique within a region."

Comment: Sure, looks right. But it does not seem to be enforced by cloudformation. I can deploy multiple stacks with the same outputs without errors

Comment: @Alex5207 There is a distinction between an output and an export. The output is just an output. An export is an output that has been exported to be consumed elsewhere (for example by another cloudformation stack). These exports must be unique, because it would be a pain if you have the same name in several cloudoformation stacks. The normal cloudformatino outputs do not have this restriction.

Comment: @Sinux1 That's exactly what I figured out as well! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Avoid using hardcoded indexes such as [0]. This will lead to unpredicted query returns when you have multiple stacks. Try a more dynamic query such as the following:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --region my_region --query "Stacks[?StackName=='my_stack_name'][].Outputs[?OutputKey=='my_output_key'].OutputValue" --output text
```

For your example this would be:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --region ap-southeast-2 --query "Stacks[?StackName=='mystack'][].Outputs[?OutputKey=='Ec2Sg'].OutputValue" --output text
```

Take note of `[]`. Without it, your query will not return anything.

Comment: This approach should be the correct answer if the stack name is known, as it avoids issues with fetch sizes on `list-exports` when there are a significant number of exports in the account and the information you want isn't in the first response tranche.

The `StackName=='mystack'` inside the query can be avoided by specifying `--stack-name=mystack` in the cli command. The query then becomes `"Stacks[].Outputs[?OutputKey=='my_output_key'].OutputValue"`

Answer (score 3):

To clarify the correct way of using list-exports:
There was a little bit issue on above post, we cannot use \' or \` around output name. The correct syntax is to use single quote ' without using escape character.

Example:

Using escape of tilde

```
C:\>aws cloudformation list-exports --query "Exports[?Name==\`my-output-name4\`].Value" --no-paginate --output text

Bad value for --query Exports[?Name==\`my-output-name4\`].Value: Bad jmespath expression: Unknown token \:
Exports[?Name==\`my-output-name4\`].Value
```

Using escape of single quote:

```
C:\>aws cloudformation list-exports --query "Exports[?Name==\'my-output-name4\'].Value" --no-paginate --output text

Bad value for --query Exports[?Name==\'my-output-name4\'].Value: Bad jmespath expression: Unknown token \:
Exports[?Name==\'my-output-name4\'].Value
```

**And finally, the correct syntax:**

```
C:\>aws cloudformation list-exports --query "Exports[?Name=='myexportname'].Value" --no-paginate --output text
```

If you had errors or unexpected empty output, please be aware all CLI is case sensitive. For example, if you used

--query "Exports[?Name=='myexportname'].**value**"

The output would be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Windows AWS CLI I had to ensure the `--query` param was doubled quoted.

`` aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name <stack_name> --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==`<key_we_want>`].OutputValue" --output text ``

Failing to use double quotes, resulted in the query returning:

`Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==``].OutputValue`

Not so helpful.