# How to Pass the Output of Cloudformation to the shell script

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am writing a cloudformation template and its output some values in the "Output" section. I want to retrieve these values from a shell script to perform some other operations. If that is possible, can someone help me providing some example?

Regards
Pradeep

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628487/getting-outputs-from-aws-cloudformation-describe-stacks

Answer (score 2):

As @PicoutputCIs said, you can use `aws cloudformation describe-stacks`. But you don't have to parse yourself. You can let `aws` parse for you with `--query`. For example:

```
$ aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query Stacks[].Outputs[*].[OutputKey,OutputValue] --output text
SomeKey       SomeValue
SomeOtherKey       SomeOtherValue
```

For more options see:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get at the `Outputs` from a stack from a shell script through the AWS CLI using the `aws cloudformation describe-stacks` command, as described in the [AWS CloudFormation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-describing-stacks.html), and parsing the JSON output returned.