# AWS Cloudformation Output ElastiCacheCluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Hi everyone I'm working provision EC2 Cluster and ElastiCache Cluster together  with Cloudformation . When I create the stack with Cloudformation I'm giving an output error provisioning at EC2 instance .

The error is: Output is not found stack (like ? )

How I can receive the ElasticCache primary endpoint?

```
Outputs : 
  EndPoint:
    Description: "EndPoint Redis"
    Value: !GetAtt ElastiCacheCluster.PrimaryEndPoint.Address
```

---

```
  UserData:
    Fn::Base64:
      Fn::Sub: 
      - |
        #!/bin/bash
        echo ${RedisHost} > /tmp/redis_host

      - RedisHost: !GetAtt ElastiCache.Outputs.EndPoint
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first stack, you need to [export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) the value:

```yaml
Outputs : 
  EndPoint:
    Description: "EndPoint Redis"
    Value: !GetAtt ElastiCacheCluster.PrimaryEndPoint.Address
    Export:
      Name: RedisHost
```

And then in your second stack, you need to [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) it:

```yaml
UserData:
  Fn::Base64:
    Fn::Sub: 
    - |
      #!/bin/bash
      echo ${RedisHost} > /tmp/redis_host

    - RedisHost: !ImportValue: RedisHost
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628487/getting-outputs-from-aws-cloudformation-describe-stacks) related Stack Overflow answer.