# What is best way to create invalidation after cloud formation created cloud front?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a completely serverless solution which will create an s3 bucket and CloudFront too. Using cloud formation template from bitbucket pipeline

I also want to create invalidate for CloudFront.

1) is it possible to create invalidation in cloud formation?

2) If no, then how can I get distribution id from my cloud formation and then create the invalidation using aws cli

```
CFDistribution:
Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution'
DependsOn: UIBucket
Properties:
  DistributionConfig:
    Aliases:
      - !Sub "${AppSubDomain}.${SSMDomain}"
    Origins:
      - DomainName: !GetAtt UIBucket.DomainName
        Id: S3BucketOrigin
        S3OriginConfig:
          OriginAccessIdentity: !Join
            - ''
            - - 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/'
              - !Ref CFOriginAccessIdentity
    Comment: !Sub 'CloudFront origin for ${AppSubDomain}.${SSMDomain}'
    DefaultCacheBehavior:
      AllowedMethods:
        - GET
        - HEAD
        - OPTIONS
      TargetOriginId: S3BucketOrigin
      ForwardedValues:
        QueryString: 'false'
        Cookies:
          Forward: none
      ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
    DefaultRootObject: index.html
    Enabled: 'true'
    HttpVersion: http2
    PriceClass: PriceClass_All
    ViewerCertificate:
      AcmCertificateArn: !Ref SSMWildcardCertificateARN
      SslSupportMethod: sni-only
  Tags:
    - Key: "Type"
      Value: "Host"
    - Key: "Product"
      Value: !Ref Product
    - Key: "Environment"
      Value: !Ref SSMEnvironment
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use CloudFront with CloudFormation too and I didn' find a way to create invalidation using CloudFormation. If you check AWS Docs, CloudFormation allows 3 types related to CloudFront

```
CloudFront
  AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
  AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
  AWS::CloudFront::StreamingDistribution
```

and none of these create an invalidation. Answering your first question:

**1) is it possible to create invalidation in cloud formation?**

No.

**2) If no, then how can I get distribution id from my cloud formation and then create the invalidation using aws cli**

You can add distribution to CloudFormation template output:

```
Outputs:
  CloudFrontDistributionID:
    Description: 'CloudFront distribution ID'
    Value: !Ref CloudFrontDistribution
  CloudFrontURL:
    Description: 'CloudFront URL'
    Value:!GetAtt CloudFrontDistribution.DomainName
```

save distribution ID using bash (check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628487/getting-outputs-from-aws-cloudformation-describe-stacks)):

```
$ distributionId=${aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name MY_STACK --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='CloudFrontDistributionID'].OutputValue" --output text}
```

and, finally, create [CloudFront invalidation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/create-invalidation.html):

```
$ aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $distributionId --paths /index.html /error.html
```

Comment: Thanks, I found another way also  which is 

In template.yaml I used list exports

` CFDistributionID:
    Value: !Ref CFDistribution
    Description: Cloudfront Distribution ID
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}:CFDistributionID`

and Using CLI

`aws cloudformation list-exports --query "Exports[?Name!=null] | [?contains(Name,'xyz-UI:CFDistributionID')].Value | [0]`

Which will return me 
"distribuation-id"

and then i can use your last command

Answer (score 0):

You could use CloudFormation custom resources as well. You create a Lambda as a Custom Resource and invalidate the CloudFront cache there.