# Query AWS Stack Resource AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to Qyery AWS Stack Resource Aws Cl so I can get the PhysicalResourceId.

To describe the stacks and query it is resented in this post.

[describe the stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628487/getting-outputs-from-aws-cloudformation-describe-stacks)

If I want to describe my stack resource I use this command

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resource --stack-name banana --logical-resource-id orange
```

Is there a way to get the PhysicalResourceId from the output. which is a Json format?

```
{
    "StackResourceDetail": {
        "StackName": "strawbery",
        "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:0000000000:stack/orange/pinaple",
        "LogicalResourceId": "PotatoInstance",
        "PhysicalResourceId": "i-00000000001",
        "ResourceType": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "LastUpdatedTimestamp": "orange",
        "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
        "Metadata": "{}",
        "DriftInformation": {
            "StackResourceDriftStatus": "NOT_CHECKED"
        }
    }
}
```

I think there would be a way if I'd use awk, but I don't know how to use it.

```
awk
```

Update:

I need to use awk as it will be done in a pipeline and the pipeline doesn't have jq installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use AWS [--query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html) `--query StackResourceDetail.PhysicalResourceId`

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resource --stack-name banana --logical-resource-id orange --query StackResourceDetail.PhysicalResourceId
```

Comment: If there is an array, is there a way to use query? I think Tags are an array?

Comment: you mean `aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name banana --query 'Stacks[].Tags'`? `describe-stack-resource` doesn't return any tags correct?