# Output AWS CLI YAML output to console

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, command-line-interface, aws-cloudformation

I am using the AWS CLI and CloudFormation to create a new S3 bucket.
Here is my yaml file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Creates an S3 bucket
Parameters:
  BucketName:
    Description: Name of the Bucket
    Type: String

Resources:
  ArtifactBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain

Outputs:
  ArtifactBucket:
    Value: !Sub ${BucketName}
  BucketArn:  
    Value: !GetAtt ArtifactBucket.Arn
    Description: Arn of the new bucket
```

I run it with the following cli command in a terminal window:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name brendan-s3 \
--template-file ComposeEveryApp/create-s3-bucket.yaml \
--profile compose-staging \
--parameter-overrides BucketName=brendan
```

Everything works fine.  Here is the new bucket displayed in the AWS console:
[image]
I'd like to display the Arn of the new bucket (as shown above) in the terminal window.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `aws cloudformation deploy` is only instructing the CloudFormation service to start the deployment and not actually waiting for the deployment to finish. Hence there is no link between the `Outputs` section and the return value of the command you're executing on the CLI.

If you want the `Outputs` of a cloudformation stack, you'll have to use the [`describe-stacks`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html) command, and you'll need to combine it with a client side filter using [`--query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#cli-usage-filter-client-side) if you want to only output that specific value.

You can find more info on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628487/getting-outputs-from-aws-cloudformation-describe-stacks).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [describe-stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html) command. One of its return values will be outputs of your stack.