# How can I export the AWS API Gateway Endpoints to file (or similar) after deploying?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am using the AWS API Gateway to mock different APIs and I want to use those endpoints in my application (which is not a lambda).

So my idea was to somehow reference those endpoints from a file like a json, but for that I need to get them exported every time I deploy.

Is there any way to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which stack you are using to deploy API gateway.

For example,

- Use [Output for Cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html), see below example for reference, also check [the doc to see the return value of APIGateway CFN resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-api.html#aws-resource-apigatewayv2-api-return-values). Then you can use AWS api/[awscli to get the output of CloudFormation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41629516/390513).

```yaml
Outputs:
 myapi:
   Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
   Properties:
     Name: MyAPI
     ProtocolType: HTTP
 APIEndpoint:
   Description: endpoint of api
   Value:
     Fn::Join:
       - ""
       - - https://
         - Ref: myapi
         - .execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/
   Export:
     Name: APIEndpoint
```

- [Outputs](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/outputs) in terraform
- [info command](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/info) for serverless framework

Comment: Thank you, I am using cloudformation but I still don't understand how to have an Output which places the endpoints in f.e. a txt or json file. Do you have a code snippet?

Comment: @zlZimon see updated answer with code snippet of cloudformation